# Can we replace kendo UI dropdown list with default html?

Tags: kendo-ui-mvc

Can we replace kendo UI dropdown list with default html "select -> option" elements?

I am concerned about how it is displayed in mobile devices. I want to open native apple and android interface when selecting a dropdown value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible. I will do an example with kendo dropdown and JQuery

```
<input id="DropdownList" class="form-control"/>
```

Here is a simple input box. 
We need a simple Javascript to treat is as a dropdownlist.

```
<script>
 $("#DropdownList").kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "Name",
       dataValueField: "ID",
   });
</script>
```

And to bind it to some datasource all we have to do is create a JQuery function to do it as

```
var dropDown = $("#DropdownList").data("kendoDropDownList");                                  
dropDown.setDataSource(someList);
```

`someList`  is a simple JSON object which we can get through ajax requests.